# Could not add items to cart file

Tags: php, html, forms, cart

I have a item.php file and cart.php file.
I'm trying to add the items from item.php file to the cart in cart.php file.
I'm pulling details of each item from the database table named: menu

For some reason, pressing the "add to cart" button could not add to the cart.php. I have tried for several hours and it still could not work. Can someone help me with this?

Here's my item.php:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Add your database connection logic here
$servername = "localhost"; // Change this to your MySQL server address
$username = "root"; // Change this to your MySQL username
$dbpassword = ""; // Change this to your MySQL password
$dbname = "fyp"; // Change this to your database name

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Check if the item ID is provided in the URL
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Redirect or display an error message
    echo "Item ID not provided.";
    exit();
}

$itemID = $_GET['id'];

// Fetch item details based on the provided item ID
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = '$itemID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $itemName = $row['item_name'];
    $itemDescription = $row['item_description'];
    $itemCategory = $row['item_category'];
    $itemPrice = $row['item_price'];
    $itemPhoto = $row['item_photo'];
} else {
    // Redirect or display an error message
    echo "Item not found.";
    exit();
}

// Handle Add to Cart action
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
    // Sanitize input data
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity']) ? intval($_POST['quantity']) : 1;

    // Create an array to hold item details
    $itemArray = array(
        'item_id' => $itemID,
        'item_name' => $itemName,
        'item_price' => $itemPrice,
        'item_quantity' => $quantity
    );

    // Add item to the shopping cart
    if (!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
        // Check if the item is already in the cart, update quantity
        $itemIndex = -1;
        foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['item_id'] === $itemID) {
                $itemIndex = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($itemIndex !== -1) {
            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$itemIndex]['item_quantity'] += $quantity;
        } else {
            // Add the new item to the existing cart
            array_push($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $itemArray);
        }
    } else {
        // Create a new shopping cart
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array($itemArray);
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo $itemName; ?></title>
    <!-- Add your CSS styling here -->
    <style>
        /* Add your CSS styles */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        header img {
            height: 40px;
            width: auto; /* Adjusted width to maintain aspect ratio */
        }

        header div {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center; /* Align items vertically */
        }

        header div span {
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #fff;
            margin-right: 10px; /* Added margin to separate user ID and cart icon */
        }

        .sidebar {
            height: 100%;
            width: 250px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            left: -250px;
            background-color: #fff; /* Change to white color */
            overflow-x: hidden;
            transition: 0.5s;
            padding-top: 60px;
        }

        .sidebar a {
            padding: 15px 8px 15px 32px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 24px; /* Increase font size */
            color: #818181;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .sidebar a:hover {
            color: #333; /* Change hover color */
        }

        .main-content {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh; /* Set height to 100% of viewport height for centering */
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .item-details {
            max-width: 600px; /* Adjusted max-width for responsiveness */
            text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
            margin: 30px; /* Added margin between photo and details */
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 500px;
            height: auto;
        }

        /* Add your additional styles here */
        form {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-start;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        label {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        select {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Restaurant Logo">
    <!-- Wrap the user icon inside an anchor tag -->
    <a href="accountdetails.php">
        <div>
            <img src="user-icon.png" alt="User Icon">
            <!-- Display user ID if available in the session -->
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                echo '<span>' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '</span>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </a>
    <img src="cart-icon.png" alt="Cart Icon">
    <button onclick="toggleSidebar()">☰</button>
</header>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="sidebar">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="menu.php">Menu</a>
    <a href="#">Order History</a>
    <a href="#">Review</a>
</div>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="main-content">
    <!-- Display item details -->
    <div class="item-details">
        <img src="<?php echo $itemPhoto; ?>" alt="<?php echo $itemName; ?>">
        <h2><?php echo $itemName; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $itemDescription; ?></p>
        <p>Category: <?php echo $itemCategory; ?></p>
        <p>Price: RM <?php echo $itemPrice; ?></p>

        <!-- Add to Cart Form -->
        <form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $itemID; ?>">
            <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
            <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
                <?php
                // Generate options for quantity dropdown (you can set a maximum limit if needed)
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Function to toggle the sidebar
    function toggleSidebar() {
        var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
        if (sidebar.style.left === "0px") {
            sidebar.style.left = "-250px";
        } else {
            sidebar.style.left = "0px";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my cart.php:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Debugging statement
echo "Debug: Session ID: " . session_id() . "<br>";

// Check if the cart is empty
if (!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    // Display cart items
    $total = 0;
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Cart</title>
        <!-- Add your CSS styling here -->
        <style>
            /* Add your CSS styles */
            body {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            header {
                background-color: #333;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
            }

            header img {
                height: 40px;
                width: auto; /* Adjusted width to maintain aspect ratio */
            }

            header div {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center; /* Align items vertically */
            }

            header div span {
                font-size: 18px;
                color: #fff;
                margin-right: 10px; /* Added margin to separate user ID and cart icon */
            }

            .sidebar {
                height: 100%;
                width: 250px;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 1;
                top: 0;
                left: -250px;
                background-color: #fff; /* Change to white color */
                overflow-x: hidden;
                transition: 0.5s;
                padding-top: 60px;
            }

            .sidebar a {
                padding: 15px 8px 15px 32px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 24px; /* Increase font size */
                color: #818181;
                display: block;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }

            .sidebar a:hover {
                color: #333; /* Change hover color */
            }

            .main-content {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh; /* Set height to 100% of viewport height for centering */
                padding: 16px;
            }

            .cart-details {
                max-width: 600px; /* Adjusted max-width for responsiveness */
                text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
                margin: 30px; /* Added margin between photo and details */
            }

            table {
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }

            th, td {
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                padding: 8px;
                text-align: left;
            }

            th {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
            }

            .total-price {
                margin-top: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <img src="logo.png" alt="Restaurant Logo">
            <!-- Wrap the user icon inside an anchor tag -->
            <a href="accountdetails.php">
                <div>
                    <img src="user-icon.png" alt="User Icon">
                    <!-- Display user ID if available in the session -->
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                        echo '<span>' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '</span>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </a>
            <img src="cart-icon.png" alt="Cart Icon">
            <button onclick="toggleSidebar()">☰</button>
        </header>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="sidebar">
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a href="menu.php">Menu</a>
            <a href="#">Order History</a>
            <a href="#">Review</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="main-content">
            <!-- Cart Details -->
            <div class="cart-details">
                <h1>Cart</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $value['item_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value['item_quantity']; ?></td>
                            <td>RM <?php echo number_format($value['item_price'], 2); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $total += $value['item_price'] * $value['item_quantity'];
                    }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="total-price">Total</td>
                        <td class="total-price">RM <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            // Function to toggle the sidebar
            function toggleSidebar() {
                var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
                if (sidebar.style.left === "0px") {
                    sidebar.style.left = "-250px";
                } else {
                    sidebar.style.left = "0px";
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    // Debugging statement
    echo "Debug: Cart is not empty.";
} else {
    echo "Your cart is empty.";
}
?>
```

I have tried debugging for hours and still couldn't figured it out. I don't thiink it's an error from the database, more from a code logic problem but I just couldn't figure it out...
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you debugged for hours then can you please give a much more precise description of what you found out, surely you can now pinpoint some line or function where the code didn't do what you expected? You've only provided the vaguest description of its current behaviour.

Comment: Sorry and thank you for reminder. The outcome is always the same and I forgot to mention it, the output on cart.php is always the same which is "Debug: Your cart is empty.". But the problem has been fixed by the answer from @Don't Panic

Answer (score 1):

The code in `item.php` will only add something to the session shopping cart if it receives a POST request:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
```

But there are no forms in the code you've shown that POST to that page.  The form on `item.php` POSTs to `cart.php`, but that page won't do anything at all unless there's something in the session shopping cart.

I guess this code in `item.php`:

```
// Handle Add to Cart action
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
    // ... all this code
}
```

Should really be at the top of `cart.php`.  That way when you submit the form on `item.php`, `cart.php` receives the POST, that moved chunk of code will process the request and add the item to the cart, and then that page will display the cart contents.

Some other observations:

- **Your code is open to SQL injection**.  [Use PDO and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496).
- There is a lot of code here which is totally irrelevant to the problem (eg your CSS, JS, much of your HTML), which just makes it harder for people to see and understand the problem.  You would make it easier for others to help if you try to [create a *minimal* example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).